# What is fear in humans and what does it do?

Tags: fear

From researching conventional understandings of fear, it can be a response to a perceived dangerous situation. But this definition seems very limited because fear seems to depend very much on context.

If someone is in a place where there is a natural disaster and there may be in clear present danger then that fear seems pretty sensible and obvious for the person to do what they can to become safe

A sportsman doing a risky activity are scared for their own safety and deal with that feeling in order to perform.

Even as I write this trying to give easy examples, these two seem very different. The first being an act of god creating fear and the second, a deliberate confrontation of fear.

What is fear? What is the effect of fear on a human? Why sometimes to humans do things that create feelings of fear? Where does it live in the mind? How /where does it persist?